# User SourceTree to pull/push from/to Visual Studio Git Repository

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

We have a Visual Studio Git online project. Sometimes Visual Studio doesn't allow us either to pull or push, then I am thinking of use SourceTree in that case.

However no matter how to I configure based on internet (e.g. using personal token access or install Git Credential Manager), SourceTree always tells me "Timeout".

I am using the latest SourceTree and VS2015.

Please help if you once got it work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this, https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/SourceTree-Pulls-Push-Timeout-Fail-until-Pull-completed-from/qaq-p/56248

Comment: Steps to configure, https://adamprescott.net/2015/01/29/visual-studio-online-and-sourcetree/

Comment: Hi Mazzu, I have tried your link before and after putting URL in and tab out, SourceTree says "This is not a valid source PATH/URL" and details still shows "Time out".

Comment: Oh, I see, let me check

Comment: Try this https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/Connect-to-visualstudio-com-hosted-GIT-repository-with/qaq-p/446486

Comment: Also, this can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941306/how-do-i-configure-visual-studio-2013-for-use-with-git-sourcetree

Comment: @Samuel  VS is better IDE for local repo to connected with git repo hosted on VSTS. What did you do caused that caused can't pull/push? Did you add branch policy in VSTS?

Comment: Hi Marina, even if I use GIT GUI or Git Bash command line, I always get "fatal:unable to access xxxxx.visualstudio.com port 443: Time out"

Comment: @Samuel first please check if the URL is correct. And make sure the DNS setting is correct. And did you use a proxy when connect with remote repo (repo hosted on VSTS)?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using the System's Git Version instead of the Embedded Git Version. I noticed that if I did the Git commands myself, it worked fine, but SourceTree was having no luck.

Tools -> Options -> Git -> Near the bottom, click on "Use System Git"
(Screenshot taken after I applied this change)
[image: My Options Menu]

Then, click on the Terminal button

[image: Terminal button location]

Type `git --version` to see if it's what you expect. Mine showed `git version 2.14.1.windows.1` which was what finally worked for me.

[image]